# How to format fraction number to integer number with Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript

How show fraction number like `0.8` to `00` format without parseInt just Intl.NumberFormat.

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat("en", { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 }).format(0.8));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format  method obviously rounds the input if there is no fraction digits allowed.

```
maximumFractionDigits: 0,
```

Rounding is driven by midpoint rule away from zero.

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat("en", { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 }).format(0.49));
"00"
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat("en", { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 }).format(0.5));
"01"
```

Possibly you want to truncate the decimal part.

```
Math.trunc()
```

Comment: I understand use rounds value. Is this really a standard.

Comment: It seem yes. Check https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/, chapter 11.4. (Search “rounded”.)

Comment: [[minimumFractionDigits]] and [[maximumFractionDigits]] are non-negative integer Number values indicating the minimum and maximum fraction digits to be used. Numbers will be rounded or padded with trailing zeroes if necessary.

Comment: it's happy when has it necessary, not any if necessary

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is not acceptable from ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.floor` before doing the format. Like this:

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat("en", { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 }).format(Math.floor(0.8)));
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I want use just Intl.NumberFormat.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the native `Math` object?